# How to specify browser flags for Playwright component tests?

Tags: playwright, google-chrome-flags, component-testing

In a [Playwright component test](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-components), is there a way to pass flags to the browser instance that gets run? For example, for Chrome: `--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream`, `--use-file-for-fake-audio-capture`, and similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add [launchoptions](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-testoptions#test-options-launch-options) to the project in playwright.config:

```js
export default defineConfig({
  // ..
  projects: [
    {
      name: "Chrome",
      use: {
        browserName: "chromium",
        launchOptions: {
          args: [
            "--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream",
            "--use-file-for-fake-audio-capture",
          ],
        },
      },
    },
  ],
});
```